# Getting Error 999999 from arcpy.SpatialReference.name?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, error-999999

I'm trying to build a set that consists of spatial reference names using .name method from the arcpy.SpatialRefernce() class. When I do this for a single prj file there is no issue, but when I try to do it for a set of prjs as a loop it returns a 999999 error:

```
import arcpy

#overwrite existing output from previuous trials
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#create output file location through arcpy.env.workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\RS_Data\Python\Geog485\Lesson2"

#designate shapefile that has the desired projection
outPRJ = r"C:\RS_Data\Python\Geog485\Lesson2\StateRoutes.shp"

#call on the prj file to get the spatial reference object and name
targetPrj = outPRJ[:-3]+"prj"
SpRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(targetPrj)
SpRefName = SpRef.name
print SpRef.name

#create list of fc prjs and remove .shp file names from previous trials
x = "_projected.shp"
inFiles = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for file in inFiles:
    if x in file:
        inFiles.remove(file)

inPuts = set()
for file in inFiles:
    file = file[:-3]+"prj"
    inPuts.add(file)
    print file

for prj in inFiles:
    sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(prj)
    if sr.name != SpRef:
        inPuts.add(sr)
```

here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 323, in RunScript
    debugger.run(codeObject, __main__.__dict__, start_stepping=0)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\__init__.py", line 60, in run
    _GetCurrentDebugger().run(cmd, globals,locals, start_stepping)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\debugger\debugger.py", line 654, in run
    exec cmd in globals, locals
  File "N:\Python\Reproject.py", line 1, in <module>
    import arcpy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 927, in __init__
    self._arc_object.createFromFile(item)
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
```

Comment: `inFiles.remove(file)` looks suspect ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python

Comment: Why are you not calling the .shp directly? e.g. `sr = arcpy.Describe(shp).spatialReference.name`

Comment: I was under the impression I had to use a prj file

Comment: And inFiles.remove(file) is not causing the issue

Comment: That did it. I had to change a few other things but that was the main hang up. Thanks!

Comment: @Shaun - what did you do to fix the issue?

Comment: arcpy is case-sensitive, arcpy.spatialReference

Answer (score 3):

I would take a different approach and describe the spatial reference by directly calling the shapefile. For example:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\your\workspace'
shps = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for shp in shps:
    print arcpy.Describe(shp).spatialReference.name
```

Comment: I did major refactoring but here is the bit of code that fixed my last problem:     sr = arcpy.Describe(file).spatialReference.name